# INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY With All Permissions Granted

Tags: trigger, permissions, insufficient-privileges, fieldservice

I'm debugging an issue inside an Apex trigger. The debug logs shows an error inside the following line, marked in red

[image]

The red line is trying to insert some MaintenanceWorkRule records, which are returned by this other method(s):

[image]

When the code executes the red line it fails with the following stack-trace:

```
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: 1MP4z000000g72p: []
```

I've created a permission set and granted it to the user. These are the permissions that I've tried to grant so far:

1. Assign create and edit permissions over the MaintenanceWorkRule object.
2. Assign view and edit permissions over all the fields involved of all the objects involved in these methods.
3. Assign 'View All' permissions over all the objects involved, which are:

-Delivery plan

-Work order

-Maintenance plan

-Maintenance plan work rules

-Account

-Contact

-Work type

-Therapy

-Delivery plan

none of these permissions have solved the issue for the user.

Note 1: the Id that appears inside the error message is 1MP4z000000g72p, and it's a MaintenancePlan record. I get an error when I try to open it, and **is because the MaintenancePlan records are created right in the line before the 'red line', so they are inserted, and later deleted** because the entire transaction fails.

Note 2: System admin users **can perform the action** without issues.

Note 3: All classes involved are delared '**With Sharing**'

If anyone has any ideas abuout whaty might I check to fix this I'd be eternally grateful. I've been solcing this for 2 days with no luck. Thank you so much.

Comment: you need to check that the User trying to insert the Maintenance Work rule record has edit access on all related records, meaning all the other objects that are linked to the record you insert via lookup field. This user might be missing the edit permission due to profile or Sharing reason (because of a private sharing model on the related object).

Comment: besides the FLS have you also checked that the user you are testing with has the correct field service licenses assigned. field and object access is determined by license first and then profile/permission assignments